# Can someone explain the following code statement?

Tags: c, volatile

Can someone explain the below statement?

```
static inline void cpu_write_dtlb(uint32_t vpn, unsigned attr)
{
    asm volatile ("wdtlb  %1, %0; dsync\n" :: "r" (vpn), "r" (attr));
}
```

Comment: Looks like an instruction for controlling (writing to) the [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) - which is like a cache for the virtual memory page table / mapping if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Is this a question about the asm syntax or what the code does?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about the syntax, that's GCC inline assembly language syntax.
In particular, the `%0` and `%1` are replaced with registers where GCC stored the `"r"` arguments.

The `volatile` keyword has this effect:

> GCC’s optimizers sometimes discard asm statements if they determine there is no need for the output variables. Also, the optimizers may move code out of loops if they believe that the code will always return the same result (i.e. none of its input values change between calls). Using the `volatile` qualifier disables these optimizations. `asm` statements that have no output operands, including asm goto statements, are implicitly `volatile`.

For details on this extended syntax, see the GCC docs for [Extended Asm - Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm).

Comment: The `"r"` constraint is for a general register (as opposed to, say, memory, or an integer constant), not read. It's used as an input because it's in the set of input operands (This statement has 0 output operands, 2 input operands).

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks for the correction, I have removed the parenthetical remark.